# how do I make it so when I click a button from a foreach list, it only activates the button in that specific list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some buttons that will toggle some input text areas where I can send a message, how do I make it so when I click a button from a specific list, it only activates the button in that specific list.

I tried so many other things but I really don't know how to get this over it.
I'm kinda new to JS, I mainly do Java.

```
function showFeedback (list) {
var lines = "";
var counter = 0;
list.forEach(function (obiect) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#div"+ obiect.idfeedback +"").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    counter++;
    var style = "";
    if(obiect.feedbackType == 1){
        style = "style=\"background: green;\"";
    } else if(obiect.feedbackType == 0){
        style = "style=\"background: red;\"";
    }

    lines += `<div class="page-block"><div style="text-align: right"><a href="feedback?action=delete&idfeedback=`+obiect.idfeedback+`">X</a></div><div class="cv-block" ${style} >
    <div id="parent_div_1">
        Name: ${obiect.firstn}
        ${obiect.lastn}
    </div>

    <div id="parent_div_2" style="float: right">
        Date: ${obiect.date}
    </div>
    <div class="message_div"><p>${obiect.message}</p></div>
</div>
<button>Contact</button>
<div id="div`+ obiect.idfeedback +`" style="display: none">
  <form action="contact" method="post">
    <textarea name="message" id="umessage" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="450" placeholder="Type your message here..." style="height:115px;width: 620px"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" id="umail" value="`+obiect.email+`">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="feedback">
    <div><input type="submit" value="Send Email"></div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>`;
}); if(counter==0){
    lines+= `<div class="page-block">No feedbacks to review.</div>`;
}
$("#obiect").html(lines);}
```

Comment: `$("button")` targets ALL buttons in the page

Comment: having `$(document).ready(function(){` inside `forEach` doesn't make sense

Comment: should I do something like `$("#button"+ obiect.idfeedback +"").click(function(){
                $("#div"+ obiect.idfeedback +"").fadeToggle("slow");
            });`  ? because this doesn't work for me...

Comment: also if I delete `$(document).ready(function(){` the jquery doesn't work anymore

Comment: you should wrap your whole code in $(document).ready(function{/*code goes here */})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `$(document).ready`, it is used to make sure the markup has been loaded before assigning events. In your scenario, markup is being generated dynamically, plus document.ready inside a loop does not make sense.

The simplest way to *fix* this code is to move the `$('button')` outside the loop. After the loop, do the following

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
})
```

What this code does is add a handler on the click event of every `button` element, when the button's clicked, it finds the element which is placed [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to the button element, which in your case is the required `div` element, and show that.

Comment: should I remove the class inside the div then?

Comment: Do you mean the id? `obiect.idfeedback`

Comment: actually, yeah, the ID, my bad.    Also, it doesn't work for me. :thinking:

Comment: Yup, get rid of the ID. And no, not after the loop, my bad. Place it after your function call. So, wherever you're calling the function `showFeedback`, place this code after that.

Comment: Oh, yeah. It works perfect now. Thanks for your time.